# Display image and remove it in android

Tags: android

I want to display an image keeping the current background transparent and then remove it after sometime.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //shown an image while keeping the background visible
         //call function and perform manipulation
       //remove the image
}
```

How do i achieve this.

Comment: come on... where is your work?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this action by this way:

Create styles.xml in values folder:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>


 </style>
</resources>
```

In manifest add this style with activity:

```
<activity android:name=".TestAppActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_weight="0.52"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity: TestAppActivity

```
  package com.android.test;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private ImageView imgView;
    private Handler handler;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    handler = new Handler();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    t.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I never did this but maybe you can do this:

add to your activity:

```
Llayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
Llayout.findViewById(R.id.Imagebutton1).setVisibility(0);
};
```

or call:

Llayout.removeView(view);

don't forget to declare the layout in this example LinearLayout:

```
linearLayout Llayout;
```

import the library of the layout:

import android.widget.LinearLayout;